# Python - Running shell command and capturing the output in realtime

Tags: python, cmd

This code Running shell command and printing the output in real time.

```
process = subprocess.Popen('yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spvPvXXu36A', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline().decode()
    if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
        break
    if output:
        print(output.strip())
rc = process.poll()
if rc == 0:
    print("Command succeeded.")
else:
    print("Command failed.")
```

Comment: could you please send output

Comment: That does not look like a valid command.

Comment: Take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the subprocess module to do all that kind of stuff
I've included a small example below

```
from subprocess import call
call(['youtube-dl', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PT2_F-1esPk'])
```

[Python docs to subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: `ls` is (at least on Unix/Linux) systems also available as a binary, you are not invoking the `ls` from your shell (an certainly not `cmd`)

Comment: @Anthon yes i just gave a simple example of call and nothing was coming to my mind

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the exectuable `--youtube-dl` which probably not exists.

If `--youtube-dl` is a command you can type in from the `cmd` prompt, you should try `subprocess.check_output(['--youtube-dl', some_url], shell=True)` then the `cmd.exe` (at least on Windows) will get invoked.